# How to get difference in running balance using SQL by months prior?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have data that looks like the following, summed balances by client for certain months (September 1,2021,12:00 AM just means the month of September)

```
client_id|balance_month|running_balance
20|September 1,2021,12:00 AM|$1000.00
20|August 1,2021,12:00 AM|$900.00
20|July 1,2021,12:00 AM|$600.00
20|April 1,2021,12:00 AM|$400.00
10|September 1,2021,12:00 AM|-$500.00
10|August 1,2021,12:00 AM|$900.00
10|July 1,2021,12:00 AM|$600.00
10|April 1,2021,12:00 AM|$400.00
```

I want to get the most current balance for each client and see this difference against last month, two months ago, three months ago, and four+ months ago. (September 2021 as of this post). The total of each bucket for a given client should equal the current balance.

```
client_id|0to30|30to60|60to90|90to120|120plus
20       |$100 |$300  |$200  |$0     |$400
10       |$0   |$0    |$0    |$0     |$0
```

In that way, the binned total ($100+$300+$200+$0+$400) for each client adds up to the current outstanding balance ($1000 or $0 if the balance is negative). Also, clients may not have balances in the previous month (August) shown in the original data, then it would just be the last balance for the month prior to that.

How can I efficiently accomplish this in postgresql?

Comment: Your question says that you have the data "summarized for each month", but the sample data is missing months.

Comment: Thank you I corrected that I see how that might be misleading. Your answer is good as long as perhaps first a WITH statement feeds forward balances to subsequent months when data is not present.

Answer (score 0):

You can count back the months and use conditional aggregation:

```
select client_id,
       (max(running_balance) filter (where seqnum = 1)  -
        max(running_balance) filter (where seqnum = 2)
       ) as month_1,
       (max(running_balance) filter (where seqnum = 2)  -
        max(running_balance) filter (where seqnum = 3)
       ) as month_2,
       (max(running_balance) filter (where seqnum = 3)  -
        max(running_balance) filter (where seqnum = 4)
       ) as month_3,
       max(running_balance) filter (where seqnum = 4) as month_4
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by client_id order by balance_month desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by client_id;
```

Note:  If you want this for the explicit months, then just use the months in the `filter`:

```
select client_id,
       (max(running_balance) filter (where balance_month::date = '2021-09-01')  -
        max(running_balance) filter (where balance_month::date = '2021-08-01')
       ) as month_1,
       (max(running_balance) filter (where balance_month::date = '2021-08-01')  -
        max(running_balance) filter (where balance_month::date = '2021-07-01')
       ) as month_2,
       (max(running_balance) filter (where balance_month::date = '2021-07-01')  -
        max(running_balance) filter (where balance_month::date = '2021-06-01')
       ) as month_3,
       max(running_balance) filter (where balance_month::date = '2021-06-01') as month_4
from t
group by client_id;
```

Comment: This is excellent and very close. But I need an extra layer of pre-processing before accessing t. The original data might not have their current balance in September if they didn't have any payments/transactions in that month, same for the month prior. So this needs to be relative to absolute months for each client and not just what data is available i.e. if a month has no data it feeds it forward into subsequent months up to and including this month.